# Javascript- Retrieve specific key values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to retrieve only certain key value pair from Json object. Below the list of user with unique ids as keys.

```
var user =   {
    "987654321": {
      "displayName": "Wayne",
      "profilepic": "https://test1.com",
      "fullName": "Bruce Wayne",
      "Address": "1st Main 1st Cross",
      "dob": "Apr 1986",
      "likes": "Sports"
    },
    "123456789": {
      "displayName": "wade",
      "profilepic": "https://test2.com",
      "fullName": "wade wilson",
      "Address": "31 Main 1st Cross",
      "dob": "Sep 1993",
      "likes": "Movies"
    }
}
var final = {};
for (var key in user){
final[key] = {"displayName" : user[key]["displayName"]};
final[key] = {"fullName" : user[key]["fullName"]};
final[key] = {"profilepic" : user[key]["profilepic"]};
}
console.log(final);
```

Below is the output which i get

```
{
    "715886684760616961": {
      "profilepic": "https://test1.com"
    },
    "716503112127758336": {
      "profilepic": "https://test2.com"
    }
  }
```

I am trying to get displayName, fullName & profilepic. But i am ending up overwriting it with profilepic. Kindly let me know how to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var user =   {
    "987654321": {
      "displayName": "Wayne",
      "profilepic": "https://test1.com",
      "fullName": "Bruce Wayne",
      "Address": "1st Main 1st Cross",
      "dob": "Apr 1986",
      "likes": "Sports"
    },
    "123456789": {
      "displayName": "wade",
      "profilepic": "https://test2.com",
      "fullName": "wade wilson",
      "Address": "31 Main 1st Cross",
      "dob": "Sep 1993",
      "likes": "Movies"
    }
}
var final = {};
for (var key in user){
final[key] = {"displayName" : user[key]["displayName"],
"fullName" : user[key]["fullName"],
"profilepic" : user[key]["profilepic"]};
}
console.log(final);
```

Please refer the attached code.. 
It's simple that you are overwriting values.. so simply append by

> final[key] = {"displayName" : user[key]["displayName"], "fullName" :
>   user[key]["fullName"], "profilepic" : user[key]["profilepic"]};

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the only last key pair because after terminating the line scope against previous key is removed.

```
<script>
var final = {};
for (var key in user){
final[key] = {"displayName" : user[key]["displayName"],"fullName" : user[key]["fullName"],"profilepic" : user[key]["profilepic"]}

} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `final[key]` in every line and get only the last assignment.

You could create a new object, if there is no one and assign first an object

```
final[key] = final[key] || {};
```

and later assign the properties to it.

```
final[key].displayName = user[key]["displayName"];
final[key].fullName = user[key]["fullName"];
final[key].profilepic = user[key]["profilepic"];
```

```js
var user = { "987654321": { "displayName": "Wayne", "profilepic": "https://test1.com", "fullName": "Bruce Wayne", "Address": "1st Main 1st Cross", "dob": "Apr 1986", "likes": "Sports" }, "123456789": { "displayName": "wade", "profilepic": "https://test2.com", "fullName": "wade wilson", "Address": "31 Main 1st Cross", "dob": "Sep 1993", "likes": "Movies" } },
    final = {};

for (var key in user) {
    final[key] = final[key] || {};
    final[key].displayName = user[key]["displayName"];
    final[key].fullName = user[key]["fullName"];
    final[key].profilepic = user[key]["profilepic"];
}

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is you're three times reassigning a new object (which is created whenever you use `{...}`.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
for (var key in user) {
    // Create a new object only once
    var newEntry = {};

    // Store a reference to the original entry
    var oldEntry = user[key]

    // Copy members
    newEntry.displayName = oldEntry.displayName;
    newEntry.fullName = oldEntry.fullName;
    newEntry.profilepic = oldEntry.profilepic;

    // Assign the object
    final[key] = newEntry;
}
```

Rather than using the `.` operator you could of course use brackets and string indices, but I think using `.` is easier to read.

Note that you could also store the fields to copy in an additional array, which could be useful to be more dynamic/selective:

```
// Members to copy
var copyStuff = ['displayName', 'fullName', 'profilePic'];

for (var key in user) {
    // Create a new object only once
    var newEntry = {};

    // Store a reference to the original entry
    var oldEntry = user[key]

    // copy members
    for (var subkey in copyStuff)
        newEntry[subkey]= oldEntry[subkey];

    // Assign the object
    final[key] = newEntry;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much