# how to retrieve specific keys / values from json object and add into another json object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object as below :

```
var jsonData = [
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", COUNTRY_CODE: "BE", TERRITORY: "BENELUX", MARKET: "Benelux", REGION: "NORTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy", COUNTRY_CODE: "IT", TERRITORY: "ITALY", MARKET: "ITALY", REGION: "SOUTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain", COUNTRY_CODE: "SP", TERRITORY: "SPAIN", MARKET: "SPAIN", REGION: "SOUTH"},...
];
```

I want to extract specific keys with its values ( `COUNTRY_NAME` and `REGION` ) from each array inside `jsonData` so my final result should be as below :

```
var jsonFinal = [
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", REGION: "NORTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy", REGION: "SOUTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain", REGION: "SOUTH"},...
];
```

I could make it work but I believe there is a better way to do it. What I did was :

I loop through each array inside my json object and remove the keys I don't need but now I am in situation that I have multiple keys to remove and don't want to delete one by one.

Any suggestions please how can I extract specific keys from a json object and add to another json object ? Thank you very much.

```js
var jsonData = [
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", COUNTRY_CODE: "BE", TERRITORY: "BENELUX", MARKET: "Benelux", REGION: "NORTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy", COUNTRY_CODE: "IT", TERRITORY: "ITALY", MARKET: "ITALY", REGION: "SOUTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain", COUNTRY_CODE: "SP", TERRITORY: "SPAIN", MARKET: "SPAIN", REGION: "SOUTH"}
];



for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
       //console.log(jsonData[i]);
       delete jsonData[i]['COUNTRY_CODE'];
       delete jsonData[i]['TERRITORY'];
       delete jsonData[i]['MARKET'];
}

var finalJSON = jsonData;

console.log(finalJSON);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript- Retrieve specific key values from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367177/javascript-retrieve-specific-key-values-from-json-object)

Comment: @CharlesBamford  thanks for your time but I saw that thread and was following it but couldn't make it work on my case.

Comment: Use jQuery for manipulating the dom. This is normal js stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way in modern Javascript is to use `map` with object destructuring:

```js
var jsonData = [
  {COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", COUNTRY_CODE: "BE", TERRITORY: "BENELUX", MARKET: "Benelux", REGION: "NORTH"},
  {COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy", COUNTRY_CODE: "IT", TERRITORY: "ITALY", MARKET: "ITALY", REGION: "SOUTH"},
  {COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain", COUNTRY_CODE: "SP", TERRITORY: "SPAIN", MARKET: "SPAIN", REGION: "SOUTH"}
];

var transformed = jsonData.map(({ COUNTRY_NAME, REGION }) => ({ COUNTRY_NAME, REGION }));

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a further question concerning your solution.  Can you please advise how to escape a special character in a key with your solution ? here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f8Lr3yk4/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Unfortunately you can't use the same shorthand form if your key is not a valid JS variable name. But you can still use the "longhand" form where you specify both the key and a name (necessarily different) for the value, eg: `jsonData.map(({ COUNTRY_NAME, REGION, "order#": order }) => ({ COUNTRY_NAME, REGION, "order#": order }));`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without mutating the original array.

```js
var jsonData = [{
    COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium",
    COUNTRY_CODE: "BE",
    TERRITORY: "BENELUX",
    MARKET: "Benelux",
    REGION: "NORTH"
  },
  {
    COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy",
    COUNTRY_CODE: "IT",
    TERRITORY: "ITALY",
    MARKET: "ITALY",
    REGION: "SOUTH"
  },
  {
    COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain",
    COUNTRY_CODE: "SP",
    TERRITORY: "SPAIN",
    MARKET: "SPAIN",
    REGION: "SOUTH"
  }
];

let newData = []
for (let v of jsonData) {
  newData.push({
    COUNTRY_NAME: v.COUNTRY_NAME,
    REGION: v.REGION
  })
}

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = [
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Belgium", COUNTRY_CODE: "BE", TERRITORY: "BENELUX", MARKET: "Benelux", REGION: "NORTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Italy", COUNTRY_CODE: "IT", TERRITORY: "ITALY", MARKET: "ITALY", REGION: "SOUTH"},
{COUNTRY_NAME: "Spain", COUNTRY_CODE: "SP", TERRITORY: "SPAIN", MARKET: "SPAIN", REGION: "SOUTH"}
];

 var finalData=[];
jsonData.forEach(buidFinalData);

function buidFinalData(item, index) {
  finalData.push({
  COUNTRY_NAME: item.COUNTRY_NAME, REGION: item.REGION
  })
}

console.log(finalData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help